# Which mongo stats to use to throttle writes

Tags: mongodb

I am writing logging information asynchronously to mongodb. Since this is an non-essential function, I am looking for a way to throttle these writes so it does not impact read/writes from other part of the application.  Essentially, only write when certain stat is below acceptable level.

One stats I thought of using is "globalLock.ratio" from [serverStatus](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/serverStatus+Command).  However, this does not seem to be a moving average and not a good way to measure current usage on the database.

What would be a good stats to use for what I am looking to do?  Write lock % would be ideal, but how would I get moving average from serverStatus?

Comment: And when you throttle writes, do you accumulate them in memory? Or just discard?

Comment: I use a queue with a set size.  If the queue overflows, new entries are automatically discarded.

Comment: I'm not sure, do you need to write these logs at all? What kind of information do you want to get from incomplete logs?

Comment: I am tracking usage.  In the grand scheme of things, it is ok to miss a few entries.  And this should only happen if mongo has continuous high usage, which would cause the queue to overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things to note about your question:

1) If you want moving averages, then you'll need to keep track of them yourself in your client program.  If you're running a multi-threaded program, you could dedicate one thread to polling MongoDB at regular (1 second?  5 second?) intervals, and calculating the moving average yourself.  This is the way that MMS does it.

2) When you calculate this average, you need to figure out what a 'loaded database' means to you.  There could be many things to check: do you care about write lock percentage?  read percentage?  I/O usage?  Replication delay?  Unfortunately, there is no single metric that will work for all use cases at all times: you'll have to figure out what you care about and measure that.

3) Another strategy that you could take to achieve this goal is to do the writes to the logging collection using write concern, a 'w' value of 'majority', and a reasonable timeout (say 10 seconds).  Using this, you won't be able to write to your database faster than your replication.  If you start getting timeouts, you know that you need to scale back.  If you can't write fast enough to drain the queue, then you start dropping log entries at that time.

Comment: Thanks, sampling the total time and. lock time at interval will give me what I want